# UDP server running on Android, what to do when internet goes down and back up?

Tags: android, networking

I have a UDP server running as a service on my Android phone, Do I have to restart it every time the internet goes down and back up?

Comment: Why do you ask? Is it not working as expected? Or are you just asking? In general, I wouldn't think you'd need to restart, because UDP is stateless. There's no connection that needs to be reestablished. But there are other details that may change how it works.